# What exactly is the meaning of an inner product space?

Tags: inner-products

So I had a question which asked me to show that the magnitude of **v** vector is greater than equal to $0$ with the equality being true if and only if **v** vector is **0** vector.

The description of the question read *"Assuming V is an inner product space, prove..."*

I assumed **v** vector to be $(a_1, a_2, ....., a_n)$, but my professor circled that out and said that I cannot assume $V$ to be $R^n$.

Why is it so?

Comment: There are infinite-dimensional inner-product spaces.

Answer (score 1):

An inner product space is a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ endowed with a product that takes two vectors in $V$ and returns a value in $F$, that satisfies certain properties, called an inner product. A common example is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the dot product as the inner product, but there are many others. Further reading here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition . For your problem you may only assume that the product is an inner product, i.e. that it is a vector space with an additional product on it that satisfies all the properties on an inner product. Hint: the definition of magnitude is the same no matter the inner product.

Comment: I see your point. But how do I treat it mathematically? Can I assume by vector v to be (a1,a2, a3,....) meaning it is infinite dimensional? What's the catch?

Comment: You can't assume anything about your vector, besides the fact that it lives in a vector space V that has an inner product on it, and because this is a homework problem, this is all you need. Rewrite the magnitude of v in a way that relates it to the inner product on V.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are many other inner product spaces, $\Bbb C^n$ is an example and even if you assume it is $\Bbb R^n$, what is the inner product? It is not stated what the inner product is so you cannot assume that either.